# Drill user specified tags with org-drill

Tags: org-mode, org-drill

I have multiple files with drill items. Many of them have additional tags to further categorize the drill question.

1. There are times where I don't want to drill all due items but just the ones that are tagged a specific word (e.g. :spanish:)
2. Other times, I would like to get drilled in order (e.g., first drill all items that are additionally to :drill: also tagged :python:, then continue with :cpp:, etc.). I don't like mixing completely different drill items, but they are mixed in my files for different reasons.

org-drill does provide the custom variable `org-drill-question-tag` to change the name of the tag which org-drill looks for, but I don't want to change this variable in my .emacs file every time I use org-drill.

How can I achieve my two requirements? Are there already any kind of functions in place that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found any in-place function that could do any of my two requirements, but I defined a function for my first requirement. Hopefully, somebody else finds this useful (or has even a better solution):

`(defun custom/org-drill-tag(tag)
  "Start org-drill with a user chosen question tag."
  (interactive "sInput the tag to drill: ")
  (custom-set-variables
   '(org-drill-question-tag tag))
  (org-drill)
  (custom-set-variables
   '(org-drill-question-tag "drill")))`

I haven't figured out how to achieve my second requirement though.